# Metrics values are equal while training and testing a model

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, scikit-learn, tensorflow

I'm working on a neural network model with python using Keras with TensorFlow backend. Dataset contains two sequences with a result which can be 1 or 0 and positives to negatives ratio in dataset is 1 to 9. Model gets the two sequences as input and outputs a probability. At first my model had a Dense layer with one hidden unit and sigmoid activation function as output but then I changed my models last layer to a Dense with two hidden unit and softmax activation function and changed my dataset's result using Keras `to_categorical` function. After these changes the model metrics which contains Accuracy, Precision, Recall, F1, AUC are all equal and has a high and wrong value. Here are the implementation I used for those metrics

```
def recall(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall

def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

def f1(y_true, y_pred):
    precisionValue = precision(y_true, y_pred)
    recallValue = recall(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precisionValue*recallValue)/(precisionValue+recallValue+K.epsilon()))

def auc(y_true, y_pred):
    auc = tf.metrics.auc(y_true, y_pred)[1]
    K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    return auc
```

and here is the training result

```
Epoch 1/5
4026/4026 [==============================] - 17s 4ms/step - loss: 1.4511 - acc: 0.9044 - f1: 0.9044 - auc: 0.8999 - precision: 0.9044 - recall: 0.9044
Epoch 2/5
4026/4026 [==============================] - 15s 4ms/step - loss: 1.4573 - acc: 0.9091 - f1: 0.9091 - auc: 0.9087 - precision: 0.9091 - recall: 0.9091
Epoch 3/5
4026/4026 [==============================] - 15s 4ms/step - loss: 1.4573 - acc: 0.9091 - f1: 0.9091 - auc: 0.9083 - precision: 0.9091 - recall: 0.9091
Epoch 4/5
4026/4026 [==============================] - 15s 4ms/step - loss: 1.4573 - acc: 0.9091 - f1: 0.9091 - auc: 0.9090 - precision: 0.9091 - recall: 0.9091
Epoch 5/5
4026/4026 [==============================] - 15s 4ms/step - loss: 1.4573 - acc: 0.9091 - f1: 0.9091 - auc: 0.9085 - precision: 0.9091 - recall: 0.9091
```

after that I tested my model using `predict` and calculated metrics using sklearn's `precision_recall_fscore_support` function and I got the same result again. metrics are all equal and has high value (0.93) which is wrong based on the confusion matrix I generated
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your data is massively skewed.

Comment: What you mean by that? I'm using a papers dataset @MartinThoma

Comment: It means that "False" is way more common than "True". Hence Accuracy is a bad measure, as simply saying always "False" has 91% accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen for different reasons:

- Your model learned to fast (less than one epoch). In this case, you need to increase the dataset (by adding some data or augmentations)
- Your loss function does not work correctly and returns zero gradients every call
- Your training model is not in train mode
- Your data is loaded incorrectly. Test what the input is for your model

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be the class imbalance problem. You have too many samples from one class compared to other. The optimizer that is trying to minimize the loss solves the problem by learning to predict the superior class in order to minimize the error - it cheats. What you should do is to give weights to the classes or the samples according to their proportion to other class(es), so that falsely predicting the minority class gets more costly, whereas truly predicting the superior class gets a cheaper reward from the optimizer.

You can find how to calculate class weights or sample weights from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44855957/10491777).

And how you should use (these are pieces from my code) in Keras:

```
nn.fit(x_train, y_train, callbacks = [es], epochs=8000, batch_size=64,
       shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_dev, y_dev), 
       sample_weight = sample_weights)
```

if you would like to use `sample_weights`. And similarly,

```
nn.fit(x_train, y_train, callbacks = [es], epochs=8000, batch_size=64, 
       shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_dev, y_dev),
       class_weight=class_weight)
```

if you would like to use class weights. There will not be any difference though, just do not use both.

Good luck!